# How to set a local image in pynotify?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pynotify

If I run the following in `python` in Ubuntu 10.04:

```
>>> import pynotify
>>> p = pynotify.Notification ("Notice","","/home/george/Pictures/test.png")
>>> p.show()
true
```

The message displays as expected, except the image does not appear in the OSD. How can I display a local image?

In fact, for what I need, it would be better if I could display a remote image. (via HTTP)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following definitely works for me:

```
>>> import pynotify
>>> p = pynotify.Notification("Notice", "", "/usr/share/pixmaps/firefox.png")
>>> p.show()
```

[alt text http://www.imagebanana.com/img/qfmebkr5/screenshot_009.png](http://www.imagebanana.com/img/qfmebkr5/screenshot_009.png)

Are you sure the image is there? With correct permissions?

Comment: It is working now... I guess there was a problem with the particular image I was testing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That works for me.  Maybe your backend doesn't support icons, or you are not noticing.  For KDE 4, it's small but definitely there in the upper-left.  Also, I don't think there's any pynotify support for remote images, so use:

```
urllib.urlretrieve("http://some/remote/file.png", "/some/local/file.png")
```

as needed.